# UWP How to use Isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, isolatedstorage

I'm currently having trouble finding out how to implement isolated storage in a windows universal project.

All I want to do is safe some text in isolated storage when a button is clicked and the be able to retrieve it later on a different page for use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` as a dictionary where you can save some primitive object.

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MyKey"] = MyValue;

if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("MyKey"))
    MyValue = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MyKey"];
```

Comment: What do you mean under isolated storage? It's similar to the old WP7 IsolatedStorage.

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting an error that says locals settings does not contain values

Answer (score 1):

You can store your app data locally in UWP, e.g. `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`, and this is 'Isolated storage' what you are talking about. Here is a code sample for you:

```
//Create dataFile.txt in LocalFolder and write “My text” to it 
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("dataFile.txt");
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "My text");
```

```
//Read the first line of dataFile.txt in LocalFolder and store it in a String
StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("dataFile.txt");
String fileContent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
```

You can also see here for more details: [Getting started storing app data locally](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/10/getting-started-storing-app-data-locally/#KZVf6RPrtTjVpsf4.97)

Comment: Do I have to loop through it to read multiple lines? every time I write to it will it save to a new line?

Comment: The method `FileIO.ReadTextAsync` will return the whole content of the file, and `FileIO.WriteTextAsync` will overwrite the content, if the target file is already exist. The code above is just for your reference, you should write code properly to follow your needs.

Comment: @WPInfo How to add a line in the header of file.